# How to Check if Delete was Pressed as there is a MoveNext Error while deleting item

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to check if the delete action was pressed in Acumatica screen? This is because I have a code for reloading the StockItems screen, and whenever I am deleting an item it gives me the movenext error, but the item is being deleted successfully. Below is my Reloading Code:

```
[PXOverride]
  public void Persist(Action persist)
  {
   persist();// this will call base Persist();
   InventoryItemMaint grp = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
   InventoryItem inv = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>.Select(grp, this.Base.Item.Current.InventoryCD.Trim());
   if (inv != null && inv.InventoryID.HasValue)
   {
      grp.Item.Current = grp.Item.Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID>(inv.InventoryID);
      throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(grp, "Reloading Item");
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the method suggested by Yura, OR you can acheive it in other way i think..

You can check the cache status of the record before calling base persist, if the cache status says it is deleted, dont do your redirect.

The code might be as below [NOT TESTED]

```
[PXOverride]
  public void Persist(Action persist)
  {
    bool isDeletion = false;
    InventoryItem  CurrentItem = this.Base.Item.Cache.Current as InventoryItem ;
    if(this.Base.Item.Cache.GetStatus(CurrentItem) == PXEntryStatus.Deleted) // Helps to check whether the operation is deletion
       isDeletion = true;
   persist();// this will call base Persist();
    if(!isDeletion)
    {
      InventoryItemMaint grp = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
      InventoryItem inv = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>.Select(grp, this.Base.Item.Current.InventoryCD.Trim());
      if (inv != null && inv.InventoryID.HasValue)
      {
      grp.Item.Current = grp.Item.Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID>(inv.InventoryID);
      throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(grp, "Reloading Item");
      }
    }
  }
```

**EDIT :**

I found that the above code will not work as the InventoryItem

```
this.Base.Item.Current // is returning null
```

and this is your base problem of movenext error, so i suggest you to update your code as follows

```
[PXOverride]
        public void Persist(Action persist)
        {            
            persist();// this will call base Persist();
            InventoryItem CurrentItem = this.Base.Item.Current as InventoryItem;
            if (CurrentItem != null)
            {
                InventoryItemMaint grp = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
                InventoryItem inv = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>.Select(grp, CurrentItem.InventoryCD.Trim());
                if (inv != null && inv.InventoryID.HasValue)
                {
                    grp.Item.Current = grp.Item.Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID>(inv.InventoryID);
                    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(grp, "Reloading Item");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: hello again Hybridzz, this does not solved my problem. Can i just change my question to how can I just clear the Stock Items screen after pressing the delete action?

Comment: Hi Angelo,  isDeletion, is not setting as true when you do the deletion? If it is setting as true, the below if block will not be executed and you should not get the movenext error

Comment: i think it's not, because the movenext error is still prompting after deletion.

Comment: Can we debug and make sure, isDeletion is not set to true; Are you getting any erron on the code i gave you? It should work.

Comment: no there's no error when publishing... sorry im a newbie here how can i start a debugger here in acumatica customization or how can i just throw a message so i know what's the value of IsDeleted?

Comment: U can add that as a new question and i will answer it, by the way i checked here the current is coming as null while calling persist, which makes the problem

Comment: ah ok... it works now i added the `||  CurrentItem == null` in my IF condition

Comment: Its not the rite way angelo, Give me a minute, let me give another solution

Comment: Please check edited answer, i found that the null is your base problem of moveNext Error. please check the updated code will help you or not. If helps, dont forget to mark as answer.

Comment: thank you once again Hybridzz, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the ways I propose you to add to your DAC field IsDeleted, like this:

```
[PXBool]
[PXDefault(false)]
public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
```

then attach to RowDeleting(). For example like this:

```
protected virtual void ShipmentLine_RowDeleting(PXCache sender, PXRowDeletingEventArgs e)
{
    ShipmentLine line = (ShipmentLine)e.Row;
    line.IsDeleted = true;
}
```

And finally modify your code to following scenario:

```
[PXOverride]
public void Persist(Action persist)
{
  ShipmentLine  line = ViewShipmentLine.Current;
  if(line.IsDeleted)
  {
      //do some logic which you consider as nesessary
  }
  persist();// this will call base Persist();
  InventoryItemMaint grp = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
  InventoryItem inv = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD,Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>.Select(grp, this.Base.Item.Current.InventoryCD.Trim());
  if (inv != null && inv.InventoryID.HasValue)
        {
              grp.Item.Current = grp.Item.Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID>(inv.InventoryID);
  throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(grp, "Reloading Item");
        }
  }
```

Hope it helps.